# If I add an anonymous jQuery function to many elements is it repeated many times?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$('#menu a[href^="/C"], #menu a[href^="/Test"], #menu a[href^="/T"]')
        .live('click', function (event) {
.....
.....
        });
```

It looks at each of the menu address links and then adds a function to each. However the function marked by ..... is about twenty lines long and I have up to one hundred address links.

When coded this way does this mean that all of those twenty lines are added to each of the hundred links?  Should I change this to use a named function or is that anonymous function created with a system generated name and not stored internally for every link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using event delegation, therefore the event is only bound to the `document`. So, no, those twenty lines are only bound in one place.

Please use either the `delegate` method or the `on` method, `.live` is depreciated in newer versions of jQuery and is inefficient.

```
$("#menu").delegate('a[href^="/C"], a[href^="/Test"], a[href^="/T"]','click',function(){...});
```

or

```
$("#menu").on('click','a[href^="/C"], a[href^="/Test"], a[href^="/T"]',function(){...});
```

If you are using a very old version of jQuery and must use `.live`, try this syntax instead, it is a little more efficient for your usecase, however must be within a $(document).ready()

```
$('a[href^="/C"], a[href^="/Test"], a[href^="/T"]','#menu').live('click',function(){...});
```

Comment: Older versions of JQuery should have `delegate` and the JQuery documentation on 'live' also states to use `delegate` in older version of jquery instead of `live` and `on` in newer version , 1.7 and later I think.

Comment: jQuery 1.2 and 1.3 did not have `.delegate`, but yes `.delegate` or `.on` is the way to go. 1.3 is still pretty common sadly.

Comment: Nice one, didn't know jQuery that far back :) The docs only say pre 1.7. Again, nice one. That is very important to know if you happen to use 1.3 or older.

Comment: 1.2 didn't have `.live`, but it did have a plugin called `livequery` that accomplished the same goal.